# Nashorn loadWithNewGlobal functional details

Tags: javascript, java, nashorn, scriptengine

I could see only simple reference for the usage of loadWithNewGlobal in nashorn.

I just wanted to know how to execute the some large content of JavaScirpt in nashorn using loadWithNewGlobal.My javascript content will have several JS method's.

Below the simple JavaScript content which will work fine in when using loadWithNewGlobal.

```
String script = new StringBuilder("var script = 'var i = 0;i += 1;i += 1;';")
                .append("function addition() {")
                .append("return loadWithNewGlobal({ name: \"addition\", script: script });")
//               .append("return load({ name: \"addition\", script: script });")
                .append("}").toString();
```

From the above code i understood that `script` parameter of loadwithNewGlobal is a js variable and last arithmetic operation result will able to retrieved by using the callable method.

I have tried by loading a simple method in the script but getting unexpected results.

```
    String script = new StringBuilder("var script= 'var a = function testFunction() { var i = 0;i += 1;i += 1; return i;}';")
                .append("function addition() {")
                .append("return loadWithNewGlobal({ name: \"addition\", script: script });")
//               .append("return load({ name: \"addition\", script: script });")
                .append("}").toString();
```

Any one can help me out to get some good examples of using loadWithNewGlobal to get better understanding or any idea about how to execute a large js content using loadWithNewGlobal?

**Updating with More details:**
I just want to execute large Javascirpt content in parallel threaded Java environment (Java1.8). Since it is parallel threaded environment, trying to use loadWithNewGlobal to avoid global variables cross talk.

Below the sample code which i am trying and expecting result if 5 in all the 10 threads.
But getting type cast exception, also tried by ScriptObjectMirror but unable to get the expected output.

Any idea about what i am  missing here?

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.concurrent.Callable;
import java.util.concurrent.ExecutorService;
import java.util.concurrent.Executors;
import java.util.concurrent.Future;

import javax.script.Invocable;
import javax.script.ScriptEngine;
import javax.script.ScriptEngineManager;

import jdk.nashorn.api.scripting.ScriptObjectMirror;



public class LoadWithNewGlobal {

    private static Invocable invocableEngine;
    private static ScriptEngine jsEngine;
    public static String customFunction() {


        String resultValue= null;
        try{
        ScriptEngineManager factory = new ScriptEngineManager();
        jsEngine = factory.getEngineByName("nashorn");
        StringBuffer scrFile = new StringBuffer();
        String scriptContent = "var a=function() { var i=1; i+=2; i+=2; return i+'';}; a;";
        scrFile.append("function testFunction() {");
        scrFile.append("var obj = loadWithNewGlobal({name:\"foo\", script : \""+scriptContent+"\" });");
        scrFile.append("return obj;}");

        System.out.println(scrFile.toString());
        jsEngine.eval(scrFile.toString());
        invocableEngine = (Invocable) jsEngine;

        Callable<String> newEncrypt = new Callable<String>() {
            public String call() {
                String val = null;
                try {
                    val = (String) invocableEngine.invokeFunction("testFunction");
            //      ScriptObjectMirror sobj =   (ScriptObjectMirror) invocableEngine.invokeFunction("testFunction");
            //      System.out.println("The foo Value is :"+sobj.get("foo")); 

                } catch (Exception e) {
                    throw new RuntimeException(e);
                }
                return val;
            }
        };

        ExecutorService executor = Executors.newCachedThreadPool();
        ArrayList<Future<String>> results = new ArrayList<Future<String>>();

        for(int i=0; i< 10; i++){
            //submit Callable tasks to be executed by thread pool
            //add Future to the list, we can get return value using Future
            results.add(executor.submit(newEncrypt));

        }


        for(Future<String> fut : results){
             System.out.println(new Date()+ "::"+fut.get().toString());
         }
         executor.shutdown();

        }catch(Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return resultValue;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("Result :"+customFunction());
    }

}
```

Comment: Not related to your question, but you don't need a StringBuilder when concatenating static Strings. The compiler will optimize "foo" + "bar".

Comment: @Sebastian, Thanks for your suggestion. I have written the about code just understand the logics.. just to differentiate load & loadWithNewGlobal...

Answer (score 0):

The question is not very clear to me. Please note that you're defining a variable with function value and so overall script evaluates to "undefined" (as this is a variable declaration statement)
In the following modification, I've added "a" after var decl. statement:

```
var obj = loadWithNewGlobal({
   name: "foo",
   script: "var a = function() { print('hello') }; a"
});

print(obj);
obj()
```

With that change, function object is returned as value of loadWithNewGlobal call - and you can call it.

The only difference b/w "load" and "loadWithNewGlobal" is this: the latter creates a fresh ECMAScript global scope object and evaluates script in it and so returned values are all script object "mirrors" - but mirrors are transparently treated like normal objects as much as possible.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to run javascript code concurrently then you'll need multiple engines as Nashorn engines are not thread safe. There is some synchronization going on preventing the worst, but it isn't thread safe. Neither are its Script objects thread safe.

@a-sundararajan please correct me if I'm mistaken.

Comment: This is incorrect, you just need new Bindings for each thread

Comment: Hi @Archmede, careful, because with the bindings you can use the engine in a different thread, but it doesn't mean that it allows you to run against the same engine in multiple threads concurrently.